# How can I run a LINQPad query using my project EF C# classes?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I have the following C# code:

```
   questions = _questionsRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(q => q.Problem.SubTopic.TopicId == topicId || topicId == 0)
        .Where(q => q.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId || questionStatusId == 0)
        .Where(q => q.AssignedTo == assignedTo || assignedTo == "0")
        .Where(q => q.ModifiedBy == modifiedBy || modifiedBy == "0")
        .Include(q => q.Problem)
        .Include(q => q.Answers)
        .ToList();
```

I just downloaded LINQPad 4. I'd like to run this but I am not sure where to start. How can I add in the classes from my Entity Framework. Can someone give me some pointers.

Comment: have you looked at the documentation?  e.g. http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

> Add connection ==> Use a typed data context from your own assembly ==>
>   Entity Framework

Click Next and locate the dll with the assembly.